# Is there a way to have tag suggestions?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Knowing the advances in AI and the like, is there any way to have the system suggest proper tags based on keywords and content? I find that, often, I don't know what to tag something or I just try typing in any words or ideas to see what tags pop up as related to my letters of choice.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/automatically-determine-tags-while-writing-a-question

Comment: @Alex (or anyone) Have you ever seen that feature working here?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I’ve seen it work on meta.stackexchange.com but not here.

Comment: This exists on StackOverflow as well.

Comment: Our very own HodofHod has [created such a script](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/Installing.md). Sadly, it doesn't seem to work with the new SE site design (as is true for several userscripts).